# Can a child absolute element go under parent inline element

Tags: css

I want to make a tab style so the bottom of the tab doesn't have an underline.  To do this I thought I could set bottom border color of tab and then make child menu go underneath.

I am not sure if that is possible though.

This excerpt is taken from site, it is done like this as the child menu is usually shown on hover.

```css
body {
  background-color: #000;
}

.desktop-menu {
  color: #fff;
  list-style: none;
}
.desktop-menu a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.desktop-menu > li {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 60px;
  margin-left: 25px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-bottom-color: blue;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 20;
}
.desktop-menu ul {
  background-color: blue;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: -1px;
  flex-direction: column;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  background-color: darkblue li;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}
.desktop-menu .has-sub:hover {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}
.desktop-menu .has-sub:hover ul {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<ul class="desktop-menu">
  <li class="has-sub"><a href="#">Products</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Product name 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Prod name 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I am trying to remove this white line:

[image]

What is best method to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a hack but it works.

```css
    .desktop-menu > li {
      position: relative;
      // ...
    }

    .desktop-menu > li::after {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      height: 1px;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: blue;
    }

    .desktop-menu ul {
      display: none;
      transform: translateY(-1px);
      // ...
    }

    .desktop-menu .has-sub:hover ul {
       display: flex;
    }
```

See result in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-firefly-uftoxs?file=/src/styles.css:365-523).

Note: not suitable if you are working with transparent backgrounds.
Edit: updated the sandbox to proof it works with the hover effect.